# Find explicit solution of the differential equation $\dot{r} = r(1-r^{2})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

We have
$$
\dot{r} = r(1-r^{2})
$$
and I try to derive the explicit solution. The solution is already given;
$$
r(t,r_{0}) = \frac{ r_{0} } { \sqrt{r_{0}^{2} + (1-r_{0}^{2})e^{-2t} } },
$$
but I can not see why.

Normally I would use the seperation of variables and hence write
$$
\frac{dr}{dt} = r(1-r^{2})) \Rightarrow \int\frac{1}{r-r^{3}}dr  = \int dt,
$$
but I do not know how to proceed.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Separate $1/(r(1-r^2))$ in simple fractions

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that $r(t_o)\notin\{0,1\}$ within some interval you can rewrite the equation as
$$\frac{\dot{r}}{r(1-r^2)}=1$$
Then integrate from $t_0$ to say $t$. I'll write more details if you still need help.  On the left hand side you may need to decompose the expression as partial fractions.

$$
\int^t_{t_0}\frac{r'(s)}{r(s)(1-r^2(s))}\,dt = t- t_0
$$
Substitution $u=r(t)$ gives
$$
\int^{r(t)}_{r(t_0)}\frac{du}{u(1-u^2)}=t-t_0
$$

Find $A$, $B$, $C$ such that

$\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{1-u}+\frac{C}{1+u}=\frac{1}{u(1-u)(1+u)}$

Comment: I do still need help. I can see how if $f(x) = \ln{ r ( 1-r^{2} ) }$, then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{ r ( 1-r^{2} ) } \dot{r}$ but I do not see how this helps.

Comment: Fin the coefficients $A$, $B$ and $C$ first, then the rest is straight forward: $A\log(r(t))-B\log(1-r(t))+C\log(1+r(t)) =t-t_0+ constant$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dot{r} = r(1-r^{2})$$
$$\int_{r_0}^r \dfrac {ds} {s(1-s^{2})}=\int_{0}^t dt$$
$$\int_{r_0}^r \dfrac {2sds} {s^2(1-s^{2})}=2\int_{0}^t dt$$
Note that $ds^2=2sds$:
$$\int_{r_0}^r\dfrac {ds^2} {s^2(1-s^{2})}=2t$$
Decompose with fraction method:
$$\int_{r_0}^r\dfrac {ds^2} {(1-s^{2})}+\int_{r_0}^r \dfrac {ds^2} {s^2}=2
t$$
Evaluate the integrals.
$$\ln r^2-\ln |r_0^2|-\ln|r^2-1|+\ln |r_0^2-1|=2t$$
$$\ln \left | \dfrac {r^2}{r^2-1} \right |=  \ln \left | \dfrac {r_0^2}{r_0^2-1} \right | +\ln (e^{ 2t})$$
$$  \dfrac {r^2}{r^2-1} =   \dfrac {r_0^2e^{ 2t}}{r_0^2-1} $$
You can surely finish.